# Using Linq to filter parents by their children

Tags: silverlight, linq, ria

Having some problems with my Silverlight app (with RIA services) filtering my results.  The idea is on the client I set up the EntityQuery and its filters and call load.  However this isn't working for me.

Heres my code.

```
public void FireQuery(string filterValue)
{
    EntityQuery<Parent> query = m_ParentDomainContext.GetParentQuery();
    query = query.Where(p => p.Children.Any(c => c.Name.Contains(filterValue)));
    m_ParentDomainContext.Load(query, Query_Completed, null);
}
```

Compiles just fine, however, runtime I get "Query operator 'Any' is not supported." Exception.
Does anyone know of a good way to filter like this?  Again, I'm looking for a way to set this up on the client.

EDIT: I should note, I've tried a few other queries as well, with similar results:

```
query = query.Where(p => p.Children.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(filterValue)).Count() != 0);

query = query.Where(p => p.Children.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(filterValue)).FirstOrDefault != null);

query = query.Where(p => p.Children.Where(c => c.Name.Contains(filterValue)).Any());
```

Query Operator 'Count/FirstOrDefault/Any' is not supported.  I'm clearly missing something here...

Comment: I don't know much about RIA Services, but I think it's because there is no way to represent this query so that it can be sent to the server. Perhaps you could create the query on the server and expose it to the client?

Comment: While i could do that, the problem is I may (or may not) have multiple filters i want to apply.  Applying the filters dynamically on the client would be simple if the above worked.  Sending a variable list of filters to the server?  I'm not so sure that would go over smoothly.

Comment: Could you please point me to the definition of Parent class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I tried to play around a little with this, I figured out that methods like First, Any and Count can't be used with LINQ to Entities (and, I believe, even NHibernate) over WCF RIA Services because they're not defined on the `IQueryable` itself, but, instread, are extention methods defined in the `System.Linq`namespace. That is precisely why this shows as a run-time exception and not a compile-time error. The only extension methods that can be used here are those found in `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client` (such as Where, Skip, Take, OrderBy, etc.).

This has to do with the "EntityQuery" objects, because those need to be composed and sent back to the server, whereas for the collections (such as `m_ParentDomainContext.Parents` in your case), you can use the `System.Linq` extension methods freely.

In order to implement this functionality, I suggest, as Thomas Levesque said, to expose it from the server in order to only get the data you want, or, alternatively, you can compose a query using the available constructs (the ones in `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client`) and then apply the other filters on the resulting data (where you can use extension methods from the `System.Linq` namespace).

PS: I tried this with both classic Entity Framework and Entity Framework CodeFirst, and had the same results.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After reading more and finding nothing on my own, I eventually did what Thomas Levesque suggested.  It's good to have an explanation why it doesn't/can't work, however disappointing. Thanks again.